# Execute if condition in loop in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have the method below. I want everything inside the if statement to execute repeatedly, until what is inside the constant 'oneMonth' becomes true, until Cypress finds a specific date in the page (date-fns library is used, and 'oneMonth' stores the date more than 30 days later than the current day).

How can I frame this if so that the statement repeats several times, and not just once, as it does now?

```
    const today = new Date();
    var featureDay = format ( addDays (today, 30), "MMMM dd")

    cy.get('.calendar-row').then(($el) => {
        const oneMonth = $el.text().includes(featureDay)
        if(!oneMonth){
            cy.intercept('APILINK*').as('next')
            cy.contains('Next week').click();
            cy.wait('@next')
        }
    })
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="box select-box">
   <h3 class="subtitle subtitle-create-account">Select an appointment date &amp; time</h3>
   <p><i class="text-note">These are the current remaining availabilities.</i></p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-row head-calendar">
         <div class="head-selected-week"> June 22 - June 25 </div>
         <div class="wrap-navigation"><a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-reflect-klass="nav-link" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i><span>Previous week</span></a><a class="nav-link next" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-reflect-klass="nav-link next" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"><span>Next week</span><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
         }-->
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-row calendar-row ng-star-inserted">
         <h4 class="cal-row-date">Thursday, June 23</h4>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
            }-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 form-row calendar-row ng-star-inserted">
         <h4 class="cal-row-date">Friday, June 24</h4>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
            }-->
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 11:00 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 11:15 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 11:30 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 11:45 AM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 12:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 1:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 2:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 3:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 4:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 5:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 6:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 7:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 8:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 9:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:00 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:15 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:30 PM </span></label></div>
         <div class="md-radio-tab ng-star-inserted"><input name="r" type="radio" id=""><label for=""><span> 10:45 PM </span></label></div>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
            }-->
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
         }-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
         }-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
         }-->
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope I have given you all the necessary details. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have other dates in your `.calendar-row` ?

Comment: Yes i have other dates

Answer (score 1):

You can try recursion, provided by [cypress-recurse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-recurse) plugin, in order to iterate your command until it is evaluated as true.
The advantage of this plugin is that you can control its behavior by limiting the iteration time, number of iterations or delaying it in case your app need some time to render a certain component.

```
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse';

...

const today = new Date();
const featureDay = format ( addDays (today, 30), "MMMM dd")

recurse (
    () => cy.get('.calendar-row').invoke('text'),
    (text) => text === featureDay,
    {
      post(){
         cy.intercept('APILINK*').as('next')
         cy.contains('Next week').click();
         cy.wait('@next')
      },
        log: false
        timeout: 35000
    }
  )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It goes into an infinite loop, even after finding the day 'July 22", skipping over it and clicking on next week over and over, without stopping.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
const today = new Date();
const featureDay = format ( addDays (today, 30), "MMMM dd")
cy.get('.calendar-row')
  .filter(`:contains("${featureDay}")`)
  .each( ($el) => {
  cy.intercept('APILINK*').as('next')
  cy.contains('Next week').click();
  cy.wait('@next')
  .then( (response) => {
    expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200)//Asserting for the statusCode is not needed but would recommend
  })
  })
```

Im not 100% sure if this will work as Im unable to recreate variable featureDay. I'm assuming you are trying to filter for a date 30 days from `new Data()` in format "MMMM dd". With the HTML you posted are you 100% certain this query is suppose to return more than 1 element. `<div class ="head-selected-week"> June 22 - June 25 </div` shows that the only possible dates for `h4 class="cal-row-date"` are June 22-25. Another way to put this is, if you are selecting `.calendar-row` the child `h4 class="cal-row-date` will never contain a date 30 days from new Date().

Comment: I have this error: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: contains("July 22")"

Comment: Sorry I forgot a `:` in `.filter(':contains("${featureDay}")')`

Comment: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: :contains("July 23"), but never found it. Queried from element: <div.col-lg-12.col-xs-12.form-row.calendar-row.ng-star-inserted>

Comment: Im picturing what your testing as something similar to the vaccine signups. Where you have a calendar with days and time slots. You are filtering for July 23. Based on your HTML you are only displaying one week at a time. You need to first interact with the navigation to cause the date range to display the week containing July 23. Otherwise, your query will always timeout. The easiest way to do this would be to click on the span labeled next week x number of times until week includes July 23rd. `cy.contains('span', 'Next week').click()`

Comment: Yes, your association with vaccines is a good one. The point is that I tried it and as you said last time, it clicks once on 'Next week' , then searches directly for 'featureDay' and automatically generates the error